# Join sql table on key from jsonb array column in one table to field on another table

Tags: sql, postgresql, jsonb, jsonb-array-elements

I have **users** table which has a cart column of type jsonb array, for example:

```
[{"product_id": 1, "qty": 2}, 
 {"product_id": 2, "qty": 3}]
```

and **products** table that has primary key `product_id`.

I want to retrive all the products that are present in the documents in the cart column of the **users** table.

Comment: Hello and welcome! Please add the SQL query you've attempted yet.

Comment: Any reason why you’ve repeated the same paragraph twice?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Are you trying to get one long list of products that were added to at least one cart, ever, or do you want a list of product info individually for each cart that added them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use built-in functions like jsonb_to_recordset to expand the proucts jsonb and join to products table. ie:

```
select p.product_id, products.name, p.qty
from usercarts uc,
     lateral jsonb_to_recordset(uc.products) as p(product_id int, qty int)
         left join products on p.product_id = products.product_id
where user_id = 1;
```

[DBFiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/rR4G1mX8)